What is the best translation of the phrase "Live a nice life"?
I am asking for help with translating the phrase "Live a Nice Life".
When I input it into Google I get "vita a nice vita".
I am not fully versed in Latin but I was curious if there is any better translation for the phrase as a whole
Or a translation off the word nice at all as I wasn't able to find one during my search.
Any help is much appreciated!

"Iucundam vitam vivere" is how I would say that. I would use the verb "vivere" instead of the verbs "habitare" or "convisare" because they all have slightly different meanings and take different direct objects, because you can "live" many different things (e.g. to live/or to not die, to live in a house in the sense as to dwell, and to live a specific lifestyle).
In terms of semantics, I would also use "vitam" as opposed to other words because it is more closely related to one's external existence rather than to ones independent soul. Lastly,"Iucundam" directly translated to "pleasant" or "delightful."

+1. I agree vitam vivere is the best phrase here for "to live a life" and is amply attested in Latin literature. Vitam habitare would mean instead "to inhabit a life", and I don't think that's what OP is going for. You do also have vitam colere, which means "to spend one's life", and that could work here as well.

Thank you so much for the help! I really appreciate the insight!

If you want the imperative, don't forget to conjugate vivere: jucundum vitam vive.

@DevonGrant Make sure you see Figulus' comment above, too!
